# Multiple events triggering same function (specific case)

Tags: jquery, triggers, bind

I'v read around that you could bind different events using bind() function obviously. But i'm having troubles understanding the syntax, especially when there are specific functions like keydown, that take arguments. Here's my code example:

```
            $('#closePopup').click(function(){
                popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut();
            });
            $(document).keydown(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode==27){
                    popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut();
                }
            });
```

Is there a way to bind/on those 2 triggers, so i can avoid duplicating popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut(); statement? Like (on click and keypress(e)) do this

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind different events to different objects in one statement unfortunately.

You could put that code in a function and call that function in both the events to avoid duplicating the code:

```
function closePopupbg(){
    popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut();
}

$('#closePopup').click(closePopupbg);
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        closePopupbg();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to define `popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut();` in a function and then call it from however many events you define:

```
    var someFunctionName = function(){
         popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut();
    };

    $('#closePopup').click(function(){
        someFunctionName();
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27){
            someFunctionName();
        }
    });
```

*** EDIT ****
I have not tested this code in any way, it is for demonstration purposes only so please don't call me on accuracy, scope, or any similar issue :).

Comment: Well not exactly, i want multiple triggers to point into single function, but apparently it's not achievable

Comment: Isn't this what I've illustrated above? Both the click event and keydown event would call the predefined function.

Comment: Well not in that sense, my primary goal was to reduce the code used, and the technique i was looking for would stack up triggers, and then call the function only in one place in line. Altho yes you're right but you missunderstood my contept apparently

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. So where I have just swapped the function call for the code, you would just like to have had a multiple binds on multiple selectors to call be defined together and call the single function?

Comment: Ok ill pseudo code it to clarify: trigger(click OR keydown OR doubleclick){ do stuff }

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger the `click` event:

```
$('#closePopup').click(function() {
    popupbg.add(popup).fadeOut();
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('#closePopup').trigger('click');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Interesting approach but it doesn't solve my issue, thanks tho